# How to get the address of the previous page in golang from the headers? My "Referer" header is empty

Tags: go, go-gin

`

```
func temp(c *gin.Context) {
   tmp, _ := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
   err := tmp.Execute(c.Writer, "")

   println(c.Request.Header.Get("Referer"))

   if err != nil {
      return
   }
}
```

`

This code prints headers, but it doesn't have "Referer"
`

```
requestDump, err := httputil.DumpRequest(c.Request, true)
println(string(requestDump))
```

`

Comment: A client isn't required to send a referer header. Web browsers mostly will, API clients etc are less likely to.

Comment: I need a title to redirect to the previous page